# Store animated GIF image in local Storage using pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, local-storage, animated-gif

I have a requirement where I need to store the GIF image in local storage. I have been trying to do this using following code:

```
function imgToURI(image) {
    var canvasTemp = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvasTemp.width = image.naturalWidth; // or 'width' if you want a special/scaled size
    canvasTemp.height = image.naturalHeight; // or 'height' if you want a special/scaled size
    canvasTemp.getContext('2d').drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    var dataUri = canvasTemp.toDataURL('image/gif');
    // Modify Data URI beginning
    dataUri = 'data:image/gif;' + dataUri.substring(15);
    return dataUri;
}


window.onload = function () {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = 'http://pop.h-cdn.co/assets/16/33/480x264/gallery-1471381857-gif-season-2.gif';
    localStorage.setItem('test', imgToURI(img));
};
```

The above code outputs `data:image/gif;` in local storage. Also I can't find any errors on console.

I have been trying a lot but don't know why image is not getting stored. Please let me know if you have solution to above problem.

Comment: maybe when your code is executed the image was not loaded yet. So only the string  `'data:image/gif` will be saved

Comment: okay may be! You have any other option to do this?

Comment: Canvas.drawImage can only draw the first frame of any animated image. But why do you go through canvas for this? If you don't face crossorigin issues, fetch the gif as a Blob. And don't save it in localStorage but in indexedDB.

Comment: Yes @Kaiido That is what I am looking for now. Thanks! I don't think its going work like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe when your code is executed the image was not loaded yet. So only the string 'data:image/gif will be saved

```
var img = new Image();  
    img.addEventListener('load', function() {
      localStorage.setItem('test', imgToURI(img));
    }, false);
    img.src = 'http://pop.h-cdn.co/assets/16/33/480x264/gallery-1471381857-gif-season-2.gif';
```

this code will attempt to save the image only if its loaded completely

**EDIT**

You are having this error because the image the image is not coming from your server: this CORS issue. you can try this but you have to trust the server who host the image

just before the `addEventListener`

```
img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
```

Comment: Using above code I am getting error: `kraken-thumbnails.js:299 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.`

Comment: Thanks it helped. But as expected it is only storing 1st frame of animated GIF image. I will go for blob as option. thanks a lot.

Comment: you welcome. if you are having some trouble with the blob and want to do some complex thing with these gifs . look at https://github.com/matt-way/gifuct-js

Answer (score 0):

It can be due to Cross-Origin request not allowing you to get the canvas data. You have to make sure to use an image from a "trusted" source (server which allows Cross-Origin on your domain), so that your canvas doesn't get tainted.

Comment: Are you sure, because I don't think so, the link that I have shared is having any CORS issues.

Comment: I wrote your script in JSFiddle and if you debug the script up to canvasTemp.toDataURL('image/gif'); you'll get a tainted canvas error, that's why I wanted you to make sure that the server has Cross-Origin correctly set up.